# typed js not working in middleman

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, middleman

Im trying to use the typed js in middleman and i cant get it to work.

in index.html.erb

```
<span class="elementTyped"></span>
```

in all.js

```
//= require_tree .
//= require jquery  
//= require bootstrap-sprockets

<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="typed.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $(".elementTyped").typed({
            strings: ["My name is example", "I am a developer"],
            typeSpeed: 0
        });
    });
</script>
```

in layout

```
<%= javascript_include_tag  "all" %>
```

im clearing doing it wrong, https://jsfiddle.net/uw9uqc30/1/

Answer (score 0):

Primarily your problem is that you have html in a javascript file.

your `<script>` tags are html. If you look in the jsfiddle you linked you see those tags are in the HTML pane, no the javascript pane. Remove them from `all.js`.

Secondarily Rails uses another way to link resources. You see those `//= require` statements at the top of `all.js`? There's already one for `jquery.js`, you just need to add one for `typed.js`